# Returning multiple Table set with multiple queries in mySQL (workbench or cmd)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is there any ways to execute multiple queries and get multiple result set/tables as output with MySQL (workbench or cmd)?

As a simple example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1;
SELECT * FROM table_2;
```

I want to run both queries together and need 2 tables as an output.

Currently, in workbench, it returns only first query's output and Error 1064  via command line.

This feature is by default working in MS-SQL server. You just have to select both queries and hit execute. But it is not working in MySQL.

My MySQL version is 5.7.21

Comment: It's not really clear what you did. What you are describing should work. The workbench displays each result in a seperate result tab. Is maybe this causing confusion? SSMS (not sql server, but (one) client that can be used to execute queries and display results) lists all results below each other, but this is just how it is displayed. If that is not the case, and you really only get one result, please describe in more detail what you did.

Comment: You can in MySQLWorkbench.  Put the two queries in and select a blank line.  Then use the lightning bolt that has the mouseover "Execute the selected portion of the statement or the whole script if no query is selected."  Put your cursor on the blank line and hit that button.  It will run both and open two tabs in the result side of the screen.  For clarification purposes, MySQLWorkbench is different than the MS-SQL Microsoft specific query tool. They are not the same and thus work differently.

Comment: Thanks, @TGray, your solution worked. and shortcut key for the same is shift+comand+enter.
And yes, I know MySQLWorkbench is for MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is for MS-SQL.

Comment: We need an option similar to ssms, instead 2 tabs one table below another in the same window

Comment: @Solarflare THANKS. For some reason I never realized that and always used to run queries one by one.